# Use Ninject.InSingletonScope() for all classes in defined namespace

Tags: c#, singleton, ninject, ioc-container

I have a set of repositories in a class lib that are required to be singletons.
They share library with other classes as well - classes created as singletons.

Is it possible to configure Ninject to automatically use InSingletonScope() for all classes that are matching a specific criteria - for example, defined in a specific namespace?

I have between 20 and 30 repositories and from what I have found, I need to call InSingletonScope() for every repository.

I can - of course - do this by reflection, but I'm interested to know if there is an "automatic approach" to this :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Ninject.Extensions.Conventions wiki](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.conventions/wiki/Overview):

```
kernel.Bind(x => x
    .FromThisAssembly()
    .SelectAllClasses().InNamespaceOf<MyService>()
    .BindAllInterfaces()
    .Configure(b => b.InSingletonScope()));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is dealt with by the [ninject.extensions.conventions](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.conventions/wiki) [extension](http://www.ninject.org/extensions.html).